# Wordpress Blank Install Page

Tags: wordpress, installation

I uploaded a freshly downloaded copy of Wordpress 4.2.2 here: http://www.onedayonemillion.com/test/ and all I get is a blank page.

There are no .htaccess or wp-config.php files in the root directory.

No database has been connected yet.

I tried the same in another directory (/dev/) and it did the same.

I have no plugins installed or activated.

This is a fresh copy.

I added an phpinfo file here: http://www.onedayonemillion.com/test/info.php

Why can't I even get the install page to show up?

Comment: Check the error log.

Comment: where is the error log?

Comment: I also have a version set up on  http://www.onedayonemillion.com that doesn't allow me to access any widgets or the Text/Visual Tab. I brought this over from another server with a database. Could it be this server that isn't set up right?

Comment: if error reporting is on then you can track what is the exact error . add  display_errors = on in your php.ini file

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand why there is no wp-config.php in the directory, it would be good you post what is in the directory. Anyway, you can check items like (sometimes it is just that):

- some files with no ending "?>" ending the file;
- any require_once methods calling non-existing files
- (you said no, but) wp-config has wrong or non-set definitions (user, database)
- check permissions/ownership to the folder

Well, I know it can be lame, but I had problem with definition in WPLANG define, 
so I put an

```
echo "<br> there is no error until here";
```

through the files untill I find that was missing a comma at the definition. If the phrase is displayed, your installation files untill that point are working out.

Answer (score -1):

Your phpinfo says the display_errors is off.
  modify your php.ini with this line:

```
display_errors = on
```

you should restart the server after modification.

you can only track the error only if the error reporting is on in the server

Comment: Ok, I did that but where does the error log show up. I can't 'restart the server' as it is a shared server on a different companies system.

Comment: did you checked for errorlog txt file in the root directory

Comment: did you tried adding default wp-config.php in the root directory

Comment: there is no default wp-config.php file. I will try to set it up manually to a blank DB and see if that helps. I don't have an errorlog.txt in the root directory.